# Why is my URI messed up when using NavigationService?

Tags: wpf, navigation, uri

A "simple" situation:

Assembly1 contains:

- A couple of WPF Pages (.xaml)

Calling Assembly contains:

- A WinForm with an `ElementHost`
- The ElementHost contains a WPF `UserControl` that has a single Frame (=MainFrame)

The WinForm uses the `NavigationService` from the MainFrame to navigate to an absolute Uri in a like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assembly1;component/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Navigated page is displayed, all fine until now. Now when I look at the `NavigationService.CurrentSource` (which is the Uri of the currenlty loaded page) it looks like this:

[image: Messed up Uri]

All kinds of Exceptions...And what is also weird is that the property `IsRelative` is `True` and the `OriginalString` property states : "/Assembly1;component/Page1.xaml". The whole "pack-part" is lost. So when using the Uri again (what i would like) results in errors because this Uri doesn't give me a correct path anymore.

Am I missing some essential part of the NavigationModel in WPF? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Quote: "So when using the Uri again (what i would like) results in errors because this Uri doesn't give me a correct path anymore" -> seems not right, this still works. Still seems strange to me that the Uri looks messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I choose as a solution is to pick up the

> NavigationService.CurrentSource

and paste the "pack-part"in front of it again. Then use it again for navigation.